# Count emails sent by change of Label caption

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a label in my form. I want this label to dynamically change as email are sent.
The caption on the label has to  1 of 140 and so on.

I have this code within my `Do .... Loop`:

```
emailTotal = "SELECT COUNT(EMail) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT EMail FROM Names)"
```

I get a type mismatch here and dont understand why.

useful info: `Dim emailTotal as integer`

Comment: True, both will be false when declared as boolean or 0 when declared as numeric type.

Comment: It was typo error. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
sSQL = "SELECT COUNT(EMail) As ECount FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT EMail FROM Names)"
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset (sSQL)

EmailTotal = rs!ECount
```

But you could simplify with DCount or DlookUp and a saved query.

Comment: emailTotal = DCount("Email", "Names") => dCount => dim emailTotal as integer

Comment: @KimGysen ".. and a saved query"

Comment: @Remou I am getting a type mismatch error at Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL). Run-time error 13.

Comment: Try it wil DAO recordset, as illustrated above.

Comment: @Remou Worked with Dao.Recordeset.

Comment: This will be because you have both ADO and DAO libraries referenced and ADO has the top slot. Always remember, unlike me :) , to explicitly declare recordsets as DAO or ADODB.

Comment: @Remou Why is my EmailTotal giving me a value 1? i have about 130 distinct email.

Comment: That is a different question altogether. Create a query in the query design window `SELECT DISTINCT EMail FROM Names`. How many does it return?

Comment: @Remou You are right. I had populated the database with my email address so that when I click send it doesn't send to the suppliers. Just noticed when I ran the query. Thanks to you Kim and Remou.